# Removing spaces and empty lines from a file Using Python

Tags: python, file

I have a file which contains a value 2000,00.

But it contains spaces after 2000,00 and empty lines.

I want to remove all the spaces and empty lines, if some one can give some Idea, I ave tried a number of ways but no success.

One method I tired is as below

```
    # Read lines as a list
fh = open("transfer-out/" + file, "r")
lines = fh.readlines()
fh.close()
# Weed out blank lines with filter
lines = filter(lambda x: not x.isspace(), lines)
# Write "transfer-out/"+file+".txt", "w"
fh = open("transfer-out/"+file, "w")
#fh.write("".join(lines))
# should also work instead of joining the list:
fh.writelines(lines)
fh.close()
```

Comment: Without Python: `cat input.txt | egrep -v '^\s*$' > output.txt`

Comment: This leaves the spaces after the number. Maybe add a `tr`: `cat input.txt | egrep -v '^\s*$' | tr -d ' ' > output.txt`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strip()` removes leading and trailing whitespace characters.

```
with open("transfer-out/" + file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        cleanedLine = line.strip()
        if cleanedLine: # is not empty
            print(cleanedLine)
```

Then you can redirect the script into a file `python clean_number.py > file.txt`, for example.

Comment: Factor out those repeated `strip()` calls, and you're onto a winner. :-)

Comment: It's just the name of the directory containing the file named `file`.

Answer (score 4):

Another one with list comprehension:

```
clean_lines = []
with open("transfer-out/" + file, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    clean_lines = [l.strip() for l in lines if l.strip()]

with open("transfer-out/"+file, "w") as f:
    f.writelines('\n'.join(clean_lines))
```

Comment: You should add a join: `f.writelines('\n'.join(clean_lines))`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your 'lines' line to use the following generator and it should do the trick.

```
lines = (line.strip() for line in fh.readlines() if len(line.strip()))
```

Comment: `if len(line.strip())` can be replaced with `if line.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

This should work as you wish:

```
file(filename_out, "w").write(file(filename_in).read().strip())
```

**EDIT:** Although previous code works in python 2.x, it does not work python 3 (see @gnibbler comment) For both version use this:

```
open(filename_out, "w").write(open(filename_in).read().strip())
```

Comment: I think you meant `open` not `file` here.

Comment: No. I meant file. I prefer file, but according to doc (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=file#file) open is prefferable :-(

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, `file` is a deprecated synonym for `open`. It exists in Python2 because `open` is a strange name for subclassing `file` or using with `isinstance`. It no longer exists in Python3

Comment: @Jiri what is filename_out and filename_in ?

Comment: @gnibbler Oh, yes, I am using 2.x most of the time and I have not realized this! I think it's time to use open instead of file.

Comment: `open` actually makes more sense to me considering what the method is doing.

Comment: @khalid so the code written by jiri should work in my scenario?

Comment: @Jiri, both of your solutions leave spaces at the end of the lines.

Comment: @Kirill do you have a better solution coz I do not want any spaces and empty line just value as I am comparing two files !

Comment: @Kirill It does exactly what question asks for (file with number and successive spaces and newlines). Code does remove that. It may be better to clarify question by upload some test file as example to pastebin or gist.github.com

Comment: @Jiri, you are right.  Sorry, I thought that there are many lines with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Functional one :)

```
import string
from itertools import ifilter, imap

print '\n'.join(ifilter(None, imap(string.strip, open('data.txt'))))
# for big files use manual loop over lines instead of join
```

Usage:

```
$ yes "2000,00  " | head -n 100000 > data.txt
$ python -c "print '\n'*100000" >> data.txt
$ wc -l data.txt 
200001 data.txt
$ python filt.py > output.txt
$ wc -l output.txt 
100000 output.txt
```

Comment: I am sorry I am to dumb to read your code ! I have to accesss my file from a folder and removing spaces and empty lines from it !

Comment: and yeh one more thing write data back to the same file