# Removing extra space from text file

Tags: python, whitespace

I am currently keeping high scores into a text file called "score.txt". The prgoram works fine, updating the file with the new high scores as normal. Except that every time the program updates the file, there is always one blank line before the first high score, creating an error when I try to save the scores the next time. The code:

```
scores_list = []
score = 10


def take_score():
     # Save old scores into list
    f = open("score.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        scores_list.append(line)
    print scores_list
    f.close()

take_score()


def save_score():
    # Clear file
    f = open("score.txt", "w")
    print >> f, ""
    f.close()
    # Rewrite scores into text files
    w = open("score.txt", "a")
    for i in range(0, len(scores_list)):
        new_string = scores_list[i].replace("\n", "")
        scores_list[i] = int(new_string)
        if score > scores_list[i]:
            scores_list[i] = score
    for p in range(0, len(scores_list)):
        print >> w, str(scores_list[p])
        print repr(str(scores_list[p]))

save_score()
```

The problem mentioned happens in the `save_score()` function. I have tried this related question: [Removing spaces and empty lines from a file Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794245/removing-spaces-and-empty-lines-from-a-file-using-python), but it requires I open the file in `"r"` mode. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing except when the file is opened in `"a"` mode (append)?

Comment: Why do you have a redundant `f = open('score.txt', 'w')` at the beginning? If you're resetting the function, why not just truncate it and open it once?

Comment: There is no need to clear the file. When you open a file for writing it will automatically clear that file. So just open like `open('score.txt', 'w')` and start writing to it.

Comment: Why are you creating a list with readlines then appending the lines to another list? You might also want to lookup context managers and str.rstrip and you don't have to remove newlines to call int

Comment: Also, does the data *have* to be human-readable? You could use a serialization mechanism such as `pickle`.

Comment: In *take_score*, try doing `scores_list.append(line.strip())`

Comment: @cr1msonB1ade Score is a global variable that is read in the `save_score` function - It doesn't need to be referenced with a `global` statement because it is not being written to.

Comment: you could use `return` in `take_score` and then you could use `scores_list = take_score()`. Similar `save_score(scores_list)`. This way you don't need to use `global`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifically printing an empty line as soon as you create the file.

```
print >> f, ""
```

You then append to it, keeping the empty line.

If you just want to clear the contents every time you run this, get rid of this:

```
# Clear file
f = open("score.txt", "w")
print >> f, ""
f.close()
```

And modify the opening to this:

```
w = open("score.txt", "w")
```

The `'w'` mode truncates already, as you were already using. There's no need to truncate, write an empty line, close, then append lines. Just truncate and write what you want to write.

That said, you should use the `with` construct and file methods for working with files:

```
with open("score.txt", "w") as output: # here's the with construct
    for i in xrange(len(scores_list)):
        # int() can handle leading/trailing whitespace
        scores_list[i] = int(scores_list[i])
        if score > scores_list[i]:
            scores_list[i] = score
    for p in xrange(len(scores_list)):
        output.write(str(scores_list[p]) + '\n') # writing to the file
        print repr(str(scores_list[p]))
```

You will then not need to explicitly `close()` the file handle, as `with` takes care of that automatically and more reliably. Also note that you can simply send a single argument to `range` and it will iterate from 0, inclusive, until that argument, exclusive, so I've removed the redundant starting argument, `0`. I've also changed `range` to the more efficient `xrange`, as `range` would only be reasonably useful here if you wanted compatibility with Python 3, and you're using Python 2-style `print` statements anyway, so there isn't much point.

Comment: No need for `scores_list[i].replace("\n", "")`, int can handle newlines fine, indexing a list instead of just iterating over the elements is not very pythonic.

Comment: I'm sure there's room for improvement, but I was trying to avoid a total rewrite. Also, the code modifies `scores_list`, so `range(len(` serves at least some purpose. It's probably not great to be doing so in the "save" function, but I don't know enough about the program to go any further. I'll go ahead and remove the newline replacement, though - that's just unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

`print` appends a newline to what you print. In the line

```
print >> f, ""
```

You're writing a newline to the file. This newline still exists when you reopen in append mode.

As @Zizouz212 mentions, you don't need to do all this. Just open in write mode, which'll truncate the file, then write what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your opening a file, clearing it, but then you open the same file again unnecessarily. When you open the file, you print a newline, even if you don't think so. Here is the offending line:

```
print >> f, ""
```

In Python 2, it really does this.

```
print "" + "\n"
```

This is because Python adds a newline at the end of the string to each print statement. To stop this, you could add a comma to the end of the statement:

```
print "",
```

Or just write directly:

```
f.write("my data")
```

However, if you're trying to save a Python data type, and it *does not* have to be human-readable, you may have luck using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). It's really simple to use:

```
def save_score():
    with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
        pickle.dump(score_data, f):
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really answer for question.

It is my version of your code (not tested). And don't avoid rewriting everything ;)

```
# --- functions ---

def take_score():
    '''read values and convert to int'''

    scores = []

    with open("score.txt", "r") as f
        for line in f:
            value = int(line.strip())
            scores.append(value)

    return scores


def save_score(scores):
    '''save values'''

    with open("score.txt", "w") as f
        for value in scores:
            write(value)
            write("\n")


def check_scores(scores, min_value):

    results = []

    for value in scores:
        if value < min_value:
            value = min_value
        results.append(value)

    return resulst

# --- main ---

score = 10

scores_list = take_score()

scores_list = check_scores(scores_list, score)

save_score(scores_list)
```