# Python — error while writing data in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, decode

I am trying to delete empty lines in a text but when using this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794245/removing-spaces-and-empty-lines-from-a-file-using-python):

```
import io
with open("outprint6.csv", "r") as f:
for line in f:
    cleanedLine = line.strip()
    if cleanedLine: # is not empty
        print(cleanedLine)

        f = io.open('eliminado', 'a')
        f.write(unicode(cleanedLine, 'ascii'))
        f.write(u'\n')
        f.close()
```

I got this error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 21: invalid start byte.
```

How can I fix it? I found some answer here but nothing work in this case. (I am really new in programming...)

It solves the problem with the empty lines but I can't write the text already processed to a new csv file.
The text is written in Spanish. I see the errors occur while writing these kinds of letters (í, ó, etc.)

I retrieved twitter data using this code:

```
import tweepy
import json
import io

# Authentication details. To  obtain these visit dev.twitter.com
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

# This is the listener, responsible for receiving data
class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
  def on_data(self, data):
    print '1'
    # Twitter returns data in JSON format - we need to decode it first
    decoded = json.loads(data)

    if  not decoded['text'].startswith('RT'):

        try:
            # Also, we convert UTF-8 to ASCII ignoring all bad characters sent by users
            tweet = '@%s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; ""[%s]""; %s' % (decoded['user']['id'], decoded['user']['location'], decoded['user']['followers_count'], decoded['user']['created_at'], decoded['user']['utc_offset'], decoded['user']['time_zone'], decoded['coordinates'], decoded['place'], decoded['id'], decoded['created_at'], decoded['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore'), decoded['retweet_count'])

            print tweet
            f = io.open('outprint6.csv', 'a')
            f.write(tweet)
            f.write(u'\n')
            f.close()           

        except:
            pass    

  def on_error(self, status):
    print status       

# if __name__ == '__main__':
l = StdOutListener()
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

print "Showing all new tweets for"

#There are different kinds of streams: public stream, user stream, multi-user streams
# In this example follow #programming tag
# For more details refer to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(locations=[-81.397882,-4.972829,-75.288231,0.762316])
```

For the text within 'The text field', the encoding is 'ascii', but when using it for writing into the new csv file, I got the problem...

Comment: Can you post the full traceback, including which line fails and also can you provide a small sample of input data, which exhibits the issue?

Comment: Thus is most likely to occur when the data you are reading is not actually utf8. The file you're using probably has some other encoding, you just need to use that.

Comment: `0xfa` is latin1 encoding for ú.

Comment: The encoding is in 'ascii' but even using it, I got the error...

Comment: Why are you converting what is almost certainly utf8 to something else anyway? There's no reason for that at all. In your data retrieval, i mean.

Comment: Basically, you get all the data then you try to convert it to ascii, write it to a new file, read that file, choke on it, try to write utf8. Why not just process the data when you get it? It just seems you've made your life far more complicated than needed for no obvious reason.

Comment: (I am new in programming...) I didn´t notice it at the beginning... But now, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Probably change the encoding in the thing that processes to 'latin1'. Some other ideas to stay sane: switch to python3 if you can, use the csv module for reading and writing csv, don't fiddle with encodings at all unless you have to. Any modern API will just give you UTF-8.